# Sitecore 9 EXM send email cc option

Tags: exm, sitecore-forms

I have installed Sitecore 9.0.2, using EXM feature to send email from Sitecore 9 Form.

I have two email Ids for Email To and Email CC in two hidden field. So I am able to send email for Email To but didn't find any option to add Email id's in CC.

If anyone across these issue, please share your solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box it is not possible to add contacts CC in EXM.

If you are determined to do this, you would have to write a custom processor to register on the SendEmail pipeline.

```
public class CCMailProcessor
{
    public void Process(SendMessageArgs args)
    {
        if(!(args.EcmMessage is MessageItem ecmmessage))
            return;
        if (!(args.CustomData["EmailMessage"] is EmailMessage message))
        {
            args.AddMessage("Missing EmailMessage from arguments.");
            return;
        }
        message.Headers.Add("CC", "someone@just.com");            
    }
}
```

Register on pipeline

```
<SendEmail role:require="Standalone or ContentManagement or DedicatedDispatch">
    <processor patch:before="*[@type='Sitecore.EmailCampaign.Cm.Pipelines.SendEmail.SendEmail, Sitecore.EmailCampaign.Cm']"
               type="CCMailProcessor, Feature.MyPackage" resolve="true" />
  </SendEmail>
```

Comment: I advise extreme caution when modifying that part of the EXM pipelines.  Depending on the logic used could have negative side effects on dispatch.

Comment: Did you have some bad experiences Pete?

Comment: @BartVerdonck i tried same but not triggering to CC mail address , while investigated 
Sitecore.EDS.Core-> EmailMessage class do not have CC and BCC field is that the reason ? while checking the primary email contains my CC mail id but cc mail inbox ,no email  even in spams/junk

Comment: @Pankaj Kumar I was also having same issue. while doing all custom code , unable to get an email .finally i used option Quick test as an option to trigger CC emails.